# Nested conditionals in nested list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to put a nested condition in a nested list comprehension statement in python but i'm not sure what I'm missing that would make it possible, the normal loop and conditional would look like this

```
newarr = []
    for i in array1:
        for x in array2:
            if x.find(i) !=-1:
                if i not in newarr:
                    newarr.append(i)
```

and what I've gotten to through list comprehention is this

```
newarr = [[i for x in array2 if x.find(i) != -1] for i in array1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put multiple `for` clauses inside a list comprehension, and they'll be evaluated in order from left to right as though they were nested, before the actual value is evaluated or the conditions are checked.

```
newarr = list(set(i for i in array1 for x in array2 if x.find(i) != -1))
```

Using `set()` as an alternative to the `if i not in newarr` check, which is impossible to represent in a list comprehension because the list `newarr` hasn't been fully constructed yet. Instead, this will omit duplicates from the output (the last occurrence would take precedence, for the purposes of ordering).

If you want to keep the first occurrence rather than the last occurrence, try doing `list(reversed(set(i for i in reversed(array1) ...)))` instead.